Can I configure my netplan configuration so that all UDP outgoing broadcast traffic goes thru a specific Ethernet interface?
I've got Ubuntu Desktop 22.04 on a computer with 2 Ethernet interfaces. I've been reading netplan documentation for the past 2 hours and I'm running out of ideas (or understanding).
eth1 connects to the "real" network - Internet, everything.
etho connects to a closed network that has devices sending UDP datagrams. Think of it as telemetry of sorts.
I've got a program that deals with the UDP traffic - receives the telemetry and send out UDP datagrams to the devices. I'd like to configure the network setup so that UDP broadcast traffic goes through eth0 all the time.
It's going through eth1 at the moment, with the configuration below. Is what I want even possible? If so, what am I missing to get the UDP traffic channeled correctly? Thanks.
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
  ethernets:
    eth0:
      dhcp4: false
      addresses:
        - 192.168.8.1/30
      routes:
        - to: 192.168.8.0/30
          via: 192.168.8.1
          table: 101
      routing-policy:
        - from: 192.168.8.0/30
          table: 101
    eth1:
      dhcp4: false
      addresses:
        - 192.168.1.101/24
      routes:
        - to: default
          via: 192.168.1.1
        - to: 192.168.1.0/24
          via: 192.168.1.1
          table: 102
      routing-policy:
        - from: 192.168.1.0/24
          table: 102
      nameservers:
         addresses: [8.8.8.8,8.8.4.4]


I was playing with routes: type: broadcast, but get messages that NetworkManager only handles unicast interfaces. So my hopes may have been ill-founded.
